# How to calculate the sha1 hash of a blob using node.js crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, sha1

In my node.js app I would like to upload a file and calculate the sha1 .

I tried the following :

```
export function calculateHash(file, type){
  const reader = new FileReader();
  var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
  hash.setEncoding('hex');
  const testfile = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  hash.write(testfile);
  hash.end();
  var sha1sum = hash.read();
  console.log(sha1sum);
  // fd.on((end) => {
  //   hash.end();
  //   const test = hash.read();
  // });
}
```

The file is blob from selecting a  file  with a file upload button on my website.

How can I calculate the sha1 hash?

Comment: CryptoJS is mainly a client library and should not be confused with node.js' crypto module. Which one is it for you?

Comment: What's the issue with the code you've presented here? Doesn't it already work?

Answer (score 5):

if you're reading the contents in as a block, you're making this harder than it needs to be.  We do this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
export function calculateHash(file, type){
  const testFile = fs.readFileSync(file);
  var sha1sum = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(testFile).digest("hex");
  console.log(sha1sum);
}
```

Comment: The solution generated an error. Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Works fine for me once the spelling is fixed for ```testfile``` and ```testFile```