# How to calculate the checksum of a file in browser and get the same results as from windows command prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, sha1

I am trying to get the checksum/hash from a file upload on my webpage.

I am currently able to upload the file via my browser then calculate the hash using the node.js crypto library. I first convert the blob to a data Url.

```
export function calculateHash(dataUrl, type){

  const sha1sum = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(dataUrl).digest("hex");
  console.log('Hash sum is ' + sha1sum);

}
```

Result: **66b8bdd2d1d49f708722c15b26409bc072096697**

When i calculate the hash manually from the windows command prompt using the following command..

```
fciv.exe 1_1.wav -sha1
```

Result: **b06071b13a1b50cd2976ed7bb4180f6963e8db8e**

I would like to get the same checksum result from the data url in my browser as doing the manual check from the command prompt.

Is this possible?

Comment: The code you've presented here is from node.js' crypto module. This has nothing to do with a browser or [cryptojs]! Since this seems to be server code, how do you call your `calculateHash` function? What are the inputs to that function? Can you give some examples? This is basically the same comment as a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849779/how-to-calculate-the-sha1-hash-of-a-blob-using-node-js-crypto#comment63194752_37849779) to your earlier question.

Comment: Node.js code runs on the server and only communicates with the browser through requests. What kind of requests do you use? Have you read [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/1816580)

Answer (score 4):

A data url looks like `data:image/png;base64,<BASE-64 DATA>`. You would need to extract the BASE-64 DATA part, decode base64 and then run your hashing algorithm. Or - if you want to perform the hashing in the browser - use the FileReader API:

```js
function calculateHash(file, callback) {  
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    let file_sha1 = sha1(reader.result);
    callback(file_sha1);
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

let input = document.getElementById("input-file"),
    info = document.getElementById("info");

input.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  let file = input.files[0];
  
  if (file) {
    calculateHash(file, function(file_sha1) {
      info.textContent = file_sha1;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-sha1/0.6.0/sha1.min.js"></script>

<input id="input-file" type="file">
<div id="info"></div>
```

Requires [js-sha1](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1) (`npm install js-sha1`).

Credit to: [How to checksum the file to be uploaded with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177968/how-to-checksum-the-file-to-be-uploaded-with-javascript)

Comment: can you explain what to do in here :  reader.onload = function(event) { 
      var contents = event.target.result;
      // Hash your contents here...
      info.textContent = contents;
    }

Comment: *"I would like to get the same checksum result from the data url in my browser"* - my answer is: don't use the data URL, but the file content to get the checksum in your browser. You would need to plug in your sha1 hashsum generator where the comment is, hashing `content`.

Comment: Isnt event.target.result the same as data url ? What do you mean by use the file content...what part of the file blob should i use... sorry but I'm a beginner

Comment: "Run code snippet" doesn't work with this Github link. Consider using a CDN here.

Comment: @denis.peplin Thanks for letting me know, it should work again now.

Comment: Does the algorithm here loads the whole file ? If we do it for big images or let's say a video, I guess it would be better to read the file chunk by chunk so we dont overload the memory ?